# how to find if the input text is a url using regex

Tags: android, regex

I want to check if the input received is url using REGEX. How can i do it ? Is there any standard REGEX available that works for checking url?

my requirement is to check if the input text is a url or not, but not if the text contains a url.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can check without regex  in android

```
android.util.Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(linkUrl).matches();
```

Comment: hey sorry for the delay in accepting the answer. thanks your solution works.

Comment: it's ok all the best :)

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend not using a Regex in this situation as there are a lot of different cases that can constitute a valid URL (see the top voted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url?lq=1) for an example of an RFC valid regex). If working on Android I would recommend using the [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) class;

```
String urlToValidate = "http://google.co.uk/search";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlToValidate);
```

You can then look at the different parts of the URL to ensure that you are willing to accept the URL input. For example;

```
uri.getScheme(); // Returns "http", if you only want an HTTP url
uri.getHost(); // Returns "google.co.uk", if you only want a specific domain
uri.getPath(); // Returns "/search"
```